# IncludeKey Parse iOS.

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

If my object `message` has a column that's a `PFFile` called `data` (which has some audio files type data) and I have another table with a pointer to a `message` and use a relation query like so:

```
[messageRelationshipQuery includeKey:@"message"];
```

will `data` now have data, or do I need to do another call like `data getDataInBackground`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether PFFile already gotten, but it's easy to test this. Following the below code

```
if ([data isDataAvailable]) {
    [data getDataInBackground]
 }
```

Comment: my question is not whether the file is received but there the data is also received with it...

Comment: I know what you want to do, I just show you how to test this.

Answer (score 0):

The file should be returned with the object.

https://parse.com/questions/error-using-includekey-with-file-field

After reading a little around, it seems you need to load the data as well. But it should be easy to test!

Comment: so then do I still need to fetch the data from the PFFile? Thanks

Comment: I don't think so, especially from reading that comment from Parse. But it should be easy to test

Comment: @handsomeguy - I deleted my comment already :).  I swear I read that somewhere, but on further evaluation, I think you might be right.

Comment: Ok, @handsomeguy - I think the file is returned, but the data of that file will not be automatically fetched.